# Двойная группировка SQL

Tags: sql

Есть запрос

```sql
SELECT 
    Token, 
    COUNT(Token) as OPEN 

FROM 
    srvLogCmd 

WHERE  
    DATE(DateTimeB) BETWEEN '2020-09-07' AND '2020-09-07' 
AND action="OpenDoor" 

GROUP BY 
    Token;
```

Выводится таблица:

```
+----------------------------------+------+
|              Token               | OPEN |
+----------------------------------+------+
|                                  |    6 |
| 00cefd61a92728bc524f2527db1aaf36 |    2 |
| 0156bc5879e312cb1f1250064d89532a |    1 |
| 024797c18a2c1c0cd86176f838d8d0e3 |    8 |
| 0340941188947d8d2ef84ed58431f6ae |   27 |
| 03429f2992fcecc97703dedf79f18601 |    2 |
| 038ddc7c3e24cfdf417b3aa65c7e8610 |    1 |
| 039fefbd4adbb46b382e5839b6b8675f |    8 |
| 03bc907324ec716d4b4f0761378334b8 |    3 |
| 04035fbdbe18c7eeb64735e6eb96efba |    4 |
+----------------------------------+------+
```

Как теперь сгруппировать этот запрос по полю OPEN. В итоге должно быть:

```
+------+---------------------------+
| OPEN | колличество пользователей |
+------+---------------------------+
|    1 |                         2 |
|    2 |                         2 |
|    3 |                         1 |
+------+---------------------------+
```

и т.д

Comment: А внешний запрос `SELECT OPEN, COUNT(1) FROM(original query)` не рассматривается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подзапросом

```
SELECT
  sub.OPEN,
  COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(Token) as OPEN
  FROM srvLogCmd
  WHERE
      DATE(DateTimeB) BETWEEN '2020-09-07' AND '2020-09-07' AND action="OpenDoor"
  GROUP BY Token
) sub
GROUP BY
  sub.OPEN
```